# Can one user table be used for both API and regular authentication?

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I have multiple front end apps using one database. I wanted to use a single user table to authenticate users for all apps. The problem is some apps access tables in the database through regular authentication while some are isolated reacts apps accessing the database through API authentication.

My question is, can I use the same user table to authenticate users from different apps using both regular and API authentication. For your info, I am using Laravel as a backend. Thank you for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

I guess with regular authentication you mean session and the answer is yes.

Because authentication data and logic are always separated from the authenticatable table (when using jwt you get another table for tokens and with session authentication you use cache or database).

so yes you will use as many guards as you wish with the same table it will look like this in your config/auth.php file:

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```